# wierd case of 'unique' constraint (possible case for exclusion) | Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a question regarding constraint(unique or exclusion in this case I guess). I cant get my head around this simple case:

For example I have this simplified version of a table:

```
create table user
(
    id                            serial                   not null
    username                      varchar(30)              not null
        constraint user_username_key
            unique,
    is_active                     boolean                  not null,
    company_id                    integer                  not null
       constraint company_user_company_company_company_id
    references company_company
    deferrable initially deferred
```

I would like to create such constraint to satisfy following conditions:

If we have at least one (or possible few records) referencing same `company_id` (lets say = `3`) that we **must**(it should exists) have one and only one username that ends on ‘`-support`’ (lets say ‘`user1-support`’) with `is_active = True`.

Wrong scenarios:

```
• we have one or more records but there are no  any username that ends on `‘-support’` amoung this records
• we have one or more records and we have multiple  usernames that ends on `‘-support’` amoung this records
```

If we have only one entry – then username should be ended with `‘-support’`

Thanks

Sorry if question is naive

postgres 11 version

Answer (score 1):

Filtered unique index could be used:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx ON "user"
  (company_id,(CASE WHEN username LIKE '%-support' THEN 'support' ELSE username END)) 
WHERE is_Active = True;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=42415d7ac6545de3269f58b9c9735b90)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but as soon as you insert first row VALUES ('a', True, 3) -  it already violates condition: you have 1 or more redords referencing same company_id and no any username %-support amoung them. Thats why i called this wierd unique constraint case. Not only we should make sure that rows are not duplicated but check that one row with specific conditions should be present always.

Comment: @AlekseiKhatkevich The logic you described, means that first active inserted record has to be `support` type. This kind of behaviour cannot be achieved by simple constraint, the only way I could think of is trigger or creating a function that returns boolean and add CHECK constraint(the performance will be awful).